# Asp.net core razor pages [BindProperty] doesnt work on collections

Tags: data-binding, collections, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

Im trying to use `[BindProperty]` annotation in asp.net core razor pages in order to Bind an `Ilist<T>` collection of one of my model classes so i can edit some of them at once, but it doesnt work at all, every time in OnPostAsync function the collection is empty, and neither the changes that i made on data nor it default values wont post back to the server, but when its a singel object [BindProperty] works fine and the values post back and can be changed, i also tried wraping a collection (i.e `list<T>`) in an object but it didnt work either way, so is there any way for doing so or i should lets say send a edit request for every object in that collection and edit them one by one(which cant be done in razor pages easilly and need some ajax calls)??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For binding `IList` between `RazorPage` and `PageModel`, you will need to use `Product[i].Name` to bind property.

Here are complete steps.

1. Model

   ```
    public class Product
    {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
    }
   ```
2. PageModel

   ```
   public class IndexModel : PageModel
   {
       private readonly CoreRazor.Data.ApplicationDbContext _context;

       public IndexModel(CoreRazor.Data.ApplicationDbContext context)
       {
          _context = context;
       }

       [BindProperty] 
       public IList<Data.Product> Product { get; set; }

       public async Task OnGetAsync()
       {
           Product = await _context.Product.ToListAsync();
       }

       public async Task OnPostAsync()
       {
           var product = Product;
       }
   }
   ```
3. View

   ```html
   <form method="post">
       <table class="table">
           <thead>
               <tr>
                   <th>
                       @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Product[0].Name)
                   </th>
                   <th></th>
               </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
               @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Product.Count(); i++)
               {
                   <tr>
                       <td>
                           <input hidden asp-for="Product[i].Id" class="form-control"/>
                           <input asp-for="Product[i].Name" class="form-control" />
                       </td>
                       <td>
                           <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@Model.Product[i].Id">Edit</a> |
                           <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@Model.Product[i].Id">Details</a> |
                           <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@Model.Product[i].Id">Delete</a>
                       </td>
                   </tr>
               }
           </tbody>
       </table>
       <div class="form-group">
           <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
       </div>

   </form>
   ```